# How can I enable clang-tidy's "modernize" checks?

Tags: clang, clang++, clang-static-analyzer, clang-tidy

I just installed [ClangOnWin](https://sourceforge.net/p/clangonwin/),and I'm trying to get `clang-tidy`'s "modernize" checks to work. Unfortunately, `clang-tidy` doesn't seem to know about them: `clang-tidy -list-checks foo.cpp -- | grep modernize` produces no output.

The "modernize" checks are listed [here](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/list.html), but that page seems to document Clang 3.8, and the version I have installed is 3.7. However, version 3.7 is the current one listed at the [LLVM Download Page](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html).

`clang-tidy` knows about a variety of security checks, so I think I have it installed correctly. For example, `clang-tidy -list-checks foo.cpp -- | grep security` yields this:

```
clang-analyzer-security.FloatLoopCounter
clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.UncheckedReturn
clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.getpw
clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.gets
clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.mkstemp
clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.mktemp
clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.rand
clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.strcpy
clang-analyzer-security.insecureAPI.vfork
```

Is there something special I need to do to enable checks such as `modernize-use-override` and `modernize-use-nullptr`?

Comment: I came here because I wanted to *enable* *all* checks just to see what I would find. That’s done using a command like `clang-tidy -checks=* …`. I’m leaving this here in case anyone uses the same search term I did and ends up here.

Answer (score 5):

The modernize checks were added after 3.7 (ported from clang-modernize), but try adding `-checks="*"` to see the whole list of available checks.

```
clang-tidy -list-checks -checks="*" foo.cpp --
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the official binaries from LLVM: http://llvm.org/releases/download.html ? Maybe the ClangOnWin binaries are not compiled with all options, or something of that kind.